# Only execute event on outer html element

Tags: javascript, html

All the answers I could find in relation to this question are trying to do things the opposite direction. So… is this even possible?

I have a simple snippet of HTML

```
<div class="launcher" data-info="something">
  <a href="http://somplace.com">Text, or image, or whatever</a>
</div>
```

The `launcher` class attaches an event to the div, which takes the `data-info` value and does something with it (e.g. launches a video in an overlay).

How do I get only the `div`'s event to fire? (The inner link is there for no-script and semantic reasons; the full code includes various schema.org properties.)

Embedded script - `onClick="return false;"` - is not an option; behavioural coupling is evil. I have no problem attaching another event to the `<a>`, because that is a class definition. Yes, I need it to work pre IE9 (because there are people out there who…) A pure javascript (not jQuery) response would be appreciated.

Comment: "*How do I get only the div's event to fire?"* - can you explain when exactly you want it to fire..? only by clicking directly on the div?on clicking the hyperlink? how does this look like, can you share the css?

Comment: The CSS is irrelevant. The code is reusable with varying css. The example without creates a viable test.

Comment: The CSS is irrelevant. The code is reusable with varying css. The example without creates a viable test. Sometimes, there will be other elements within the `<div>`, and clicking anywhere on the `<div>` will want it to fire. Example scenario, the link is to a (youtube) video. On a tiny device, or one without script, link to youtube directly. Any other device (from the `<div>`, which includes a caption), it launches into an overlay (that's what is in the `data-…`)

Comment: The CSS is relevant. Assume the `<div>` is `inline-block` or floatted, without `auto` height` and width.. in that scenario you'll be clicking the `<a>` inside it... So in you don't want anything to happen, i guess?

Comment: So if i understood correctly, basically you want the event handler to trigger when the user clicks anywhere except a specific link..? In that case there should be an identifier for the particular link. There might be other links as well. Please rephrase your question and provide better sample `HTML` taking into account all these things...

Comment: The solution you provided below - using  `.addEventListener("click", somefunction(), true)` and `preventDefault()` does what I want. Example `<figure><a><img /></a><figcaption>something</figcaption></figure>`: click anywhere on the image or caption, and there is an associated action (say lightbox with larger version of image) - the `<a>` on the `<img>` is effectively ignored.

Comment: Okay... So is there anything i can add to the answer so that you can accept it and mark the question as solved...? :)

Comment: You could replace it with one that sums it up cleanly, as the correct answer is only in the comments; the core answer as provided would be seriously misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event.target as follows:

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("launcher")[0];
    parent.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        if(e.target.className.indexOf("launcher")> -1){
           alert("click!");
        }
    });
```

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="launcher" data-info="something">
  <a href="#">Text, or image, or whatever</a>
</div>
```

Or you can add another click event listener for the anchor and prevent it's propagation as follows:

```js
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("launcher")[0];
        parent.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            if(e.target.className.indexOf("launcher")> -1){
               alert("click!");
            }
        });
var anchor = document.querySelector(".launcher a");
        anchor.addEventListener("click",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
```

```css
div{
  height:50px;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="launcher" data-info="something">
  <a href="#">Text, or image, or whatever</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, TJ neither of these approaches has any noticeable (positive) effect. Neither option launch a confirmation dialog, and both follow the supplied link (change it from `#` to something meaningful to check).

Comment: @Rick if you click the link, it'll obviously follow it, unless you `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I tried `preventDefault()`, but it doesn't make a difference (or the examples I found don't explain how to use it properly). I would like to be able to selectively determine if the link fires, but blanket-disabling it would be an acceptable compromise.

Comment: Actually, the problem was that what I had found elsewhere was `stopDefault()`, which did not work because it is meaningless. `preventDefault()` does work, and it can be used selectively, which is perfect.